# iOS SKSpriteNode Error: assigning to 'skspritenode *const __strong' from incompatible type 'CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect')

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, collision, skspritenode

I'm working on an Xcode project in sprite kit (objective-c)
and I'm getting this error, I don't understand how to fix it, but I'm trying to get two nodes to log when they collide.

iOS SKSpriteNode Error:

```
assigning to 'skspritenode *const __strong' from incompatible type 'CGRect' (aka 'struct                   CGRect')
```

My code is here:

```
//This is the .m file

-(void) Clouds{
SKSpriteNode* character = [BBCharacter  spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"character1"];

[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"cloud1" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    if (node.position.x < -380 || node.position.y < 0){ //node.position.x < -380
        [node removeFromParent];
        NSLog(@"DELETE");
    }
    else{
        node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x - 1, node.position.y);

    }

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect (character, cloud1)) {
        NSLog(@"Intersection");
    }


}];
}
//This is the .h file
@interface{
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) BBCharacter *playerSprite;
@end
```

I'm skipping over a bunch of stuff and may have spelled something wrong...
Thanks!
Michael

Comment: `CGRectIntersectsRect` parameters need to be `CGRect`. You seem to be passing it character and cloud, which seem to be `SKSpriteNode`.

Comment: Is there anything I can do though? What do I have to change?

Comment: If what I said doesn't make 100% sense to you, this is a case of cart  before the horse. You need to take a step back and get a better understanding of variable types. There is a wealth of tutorials and reference on the internet if you are willing to spend the time to learn.

Comment: I understand what your saying, I just don't understand what I can do about it...

Comment: try character.frame and cloud1.frame

Comment: if CGRectIntersectsRect requires two CGRects to determine if they intersect, you need to give them two CGRects. So your current problem is "How do I get the CGRect of a SKSpriteNode" right ? The fact that you haven't asked that question is why I suggested the tutorials etc.

Comment: Here's a real world example -> You have a jar of quarters and you go to the laundromat, where the machines accept quarters. Do you put the jar in the coin slot ? or a quarter ?  To use that machine, you must take a quarter from the jar to put in the machine. Each SKSpriteNode is your jar. It has a frame property that is a CGRect, which defines it's bounding box. That is what you need to pass  as parameters to CGRectInstersectsRect.

Comment: I tried character.frame and cloud1.frame, like recommended, but it still isn't reading the intersection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to agree that you need to start with the basics, but it looks like comments have pointed you to using the frames to get CGRects. So with your code as is above it looks like you have 2 problems:

1. You are not passing CGRects into CGRectIntersectsRect
2. Once you correct 1, you'll have a problem where you appear to be checking the rect of "character", which is a node you make inside of the method clouds, but then never add that node to the scene. Therefore its rect will be of size 0,0. (unless your custom BBCharacter class overrides spriteNodeWithImageNamed and automatically adds it to the scene).

So, either add character to the scene:

```
[self addChild: character];
```

Or make character be a pointer to something else that is already in the scene:

```
character = [self childNodeWithName:@"character"];
character = self.playerSprite; //etc
```